# Replace member assignement with methods

Tags: c++

After having produced some code in C++, it may be necessary to change the access to a member of a structure or class to something that produces some side effects. In that sense we would need to overload the assignement of a member to something different.

```
Struct A{
int v;
}

int main(){
A a;
a.v=17;
}
```

Is there the possibility to do it somehow ? 
If there is not the possibility how would had been written the code in order to allow the flexibility to change a member into something more ?

The possibility of having each access to a memeber divided into a getter and setter seems coumbersome and impractical for any reasonable use.

Comment: _"The possibility of having each access to a memeber divided into a getter and setter seems coumbersome and impractical for any reasonable use."_ And yet that's precisely what you're asking for.

Comment: Just use a getter and setter; you _can_ implement pseudo-properties in C++ but it's an ugly and complex way of doing things. You need to get used to working in the idioms of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a proxy:

```
struct A
{
    v_proxy v; 
private:
    struct v_proxy
    {
        v_proxy( int vv = 0 ) : v{ vv }
        {}

        //Write access
        v_proxy& operator=( int i )
        {
            //Put your new code here 

            return v = i;
        }

        //Read access
        operator int() const
        {
            return v;
        }

        int v;
    };
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    a.v = 0;
};
```

Writting a generic proxy like this to allow the customization of read/writes in a common *non- get/set* syntax is easy.

**EDIT:** Some claim that this doesn't mimic correctly the behaviour of a C# property since in C# we can access `this` from the properties. Ok, just add a reference to the object and pass it to the proxy ctor. And don't forget to make the proxy class a friend of your class, to give that `this` reference full access:

```
class A
{
    A() : v{ *this }
    {}

    friend struct v_proxy
    {
        v_proxy( A& ref , int vv = 0 ) : v{ vv } , This{ std::ref( ref )
        {}

        //Write access
        int& operator=( int i )
        {
            //Put your new code here, for example:
            This.foo();

            return v = i;
        }

        //Read access
        operator int() const
        {
            return v;
        }

        int v;

    private:
        std::reference_wrapper<A> This;
    };
```

Comment: `op=` should return the proxy, *not a reference to its innards*.

Comment: Yes, and I said you can set `this` explicitly in my answer. Now though you have a reference to `this` for each property. If you have 10 properties, that means you have quite a large overhead in storing all those references.

Comment: @BrandonKohn Performance was not the goal here but usability. If there where performance issues I would redesign this thing in such way, but the principle is the same.

Comment: While you _can_ do this, it is better to accept the normal idiom of C++ and use getters/setters.

Comment: @JackAidley of course. Except in some rare cases, I would never do this. I was answering the explicit question *"Its possible..."*

Comment: @Manu343726 My point is that you cannot redesign this to avoid storing that reference in a portable way. That's why I said `It is possible to implement properties in C++, but it relies either on non-portable constructs or explicitly setting the value of this into the property instances.` I spent a lot of time working on this exact problem implementing a generic C# like properties solution in C++. The final result which didn't have the reference overhead was not portable and the interface was very difficult to use in practice when compared to regular get/set methods.

Comment: @BrandonKohn I'm completely agree with that. Pointer offsetting, isn't? Of course thats not portable ;) As I said to Jack, I would never use something like this for production code. The only case I remember was some arithmetic classes whith scalar members which should be wrapped and behave like a scalar too. But I didn't need mutable actions, so there was no this reference problem.

Comment: If you wouldn't do it yourself, why would you advocate doing it and downvote another answer which points out that it isn't a good idea?